# time[ISO-UTC] to datetime pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, utc

How can I convert the following UTC Time string to datetime in pandas dataframe?

ex. "20200114T085957600"

I tried:

```
df["Time"]=pd.to_datetime(df['time[ISO-UTC]']).dt.strftime('%Y%m%dT%H%M%S%f')
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: You need to supply a `format` to `pd.to_datetime`. For directives, see https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes

Comment: The format is at the end of my code. Do I need to add it somewhere else?

Comment: `strftime` is for **f**ormatting datetime data type to string. You need to **p**arse first (`strptime`). E.g. `df["Time"]=pd.to_datetime(df['time[ISO-UTC]'], format='%Y%m%dT%H%M%S%f')`